# Flask login/register form, error on the logic

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I want to make a login/register form on my website, for that I found this script I reproduced from a tutorial, I adapted it but it still has an error.

If I login in the register form it's logging me, if I login in the login form, the webpage is reloading. I don't know why I have this issue but please help me!

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/access', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def access():
loginForm = LoginForm()
registerForm = RegisterForm()

if registerForm.validate_on_submit():
    hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(registerForm.password.data)
    new_user = User(username=registerForm.username.data, password=hashed_password)
    login_user(new_user)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

elif loginForm.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=loginForm.username.data).first()
    if user:
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, loginForm.password.data):
            login_user(user)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('home'))


return render_template('access.html', loginform=loginForm, registerform=registerForm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your users with your login form when you use the db.session.add() and db.session.commit() functions.

This is what your login page should look like:

```
elif loginForm.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=loginForm.username.data).first()
    if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, loginForm.password.data):
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Comment: i don't know if it works, i have an other error :

werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'login'. Did you mean 'logout' instead?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it works, i have an other error :

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

there is my code :

```
@login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```